# Running the exec() function inside a cron job can't find command

Tags: php, cron

I'm using cron to run a php script at regular intervals:

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/my/script.php
```

Inside the php script I have an exec command that runs node:

```
$command_str = 'node my_node_script.js';
exec($command_str, $output_arr, $error_res);
```

Everything works great on the command line, but not via cron. So I logged the output and I get the following error:

```
sh: node: command not found
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look at [“command not found” when running a script via cron](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47800/command-not-found-when-running-a-script-via-cron) - I'd mark as as a dupe, but it is on a different site.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out thanks to a comment by John C.

What I did was use `which node` from the command line to find out where node is installed (in my case it was `usr/local/bin/node`), and then update the exec() call to use this absolute path:

```
$command_str = '/usr/local/bin/node my_node_script.js';
exec($command_str, $output_arr, $error_res);
```

I hope it helps if you run into this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conflicts with other packages, Debian dev team has decided to use `/usr/bin/nodejs` as the path for node.js. If you're using Ubuntu or Debian, you should install **node-legacy** package to call nodejs using `node` command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

For modern nodejs versions, you should call `nodejs` command instead or the full path of your nodejs installation:

```
/usr/bin/nodejs my_script.js
or
/home/user/.nvm/vx.xx.xx/bin/node my_script.js
```

Comment: Thanks. Using the absolute path did solve the problem.